# Calculated automatically completed work in TFS 2013 Agile template

Tags: tfs, agile, tfs-workitem, agile-processes

How can I implement cumulative automatically hours in completed work field? I tried to use Aggregator plugin but it not working for me. I need to sum all change in remaining work.

I used Agile template, VS 2013 and TFS 2013.4

```
 <!--Sum all remaining work -->
<AggregatorItem operationType="Numeric" operation="Sum" linkType="Self" linkLevel="1" workItemType="Task">
    <TargetItem name="CompletedWork"/>
    <SourceItem name="RemainingWork"/>
</AggregatorItem>
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Scrum Process Template I don't think you have enough data to calculate this.  The Remaining Work field is not a good option to try to capture this.  I may start the day with Remaining Work = 8, work 6 hours on the item, but at the end of the day recognize that there is still 4 hours of work left (it was bigger than originally estimated).  In that case the remaining work would only decrease by 4 even though I worked 6 hours.

If you need to capture actual work completed, you should be using a separate field on the Work Items.  Both the Agile and CMMI process templates have fields for this.  If you stick with the Scrum template I'd suggest adding a Completed Work field in addition to the Remaining Work field.

Comment: Hello Dylan, I'm using Agile process templates. I have completed work and Remaining Work but completed work is empty all the time.

Comment: Yes, you need you team members to manually enter it as it's not possible to accurately calculate it.

Comment: Case in point: Estimate was 10, remaining was 5. Just completed 6 hours and remaing is 8. This is the common scenario and not an exception. Remaining work is the only field of value.

Comment: Hello, I'm using time tracker is the only option that I founded.